# How to use new JSX transform of react 17 with react-native 0.64.0 (rc4)?

Tags: react-native

The question is basically in the title, but I've created the demo project with react-native 0.64.0-rc.4. This version of RN uses react-17, so supposedly one should also be able to use the new JSX transform. The question is whether it's actually possible, and how. When I comment the line `import React from 'react';` in `App.js`, the app creates a render error because of unknown `React` variable.

Answer (score 9):

You can refer [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/646#issuecomment-799174473)

I had suffer same issue and resolve it by changing `babel.config.js` only.

This is my `babel.config.js`.

The key is `useTransformReactJSXExpermiental: true` and `runtime: 'automatic'`

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', { useTransformReactJSXExperimental: true }],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  sourceMaps: 'inline',
  plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
      {
        legacy: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
      {
        runtime: 'automatic',
      },
    ],
    '@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread',
    ['babel-plugin-styled-components'],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

[image]

Comment: This one did the trick for me when working on a new RN TS project. In older versions we only needed to include the babel configuration specs in order to use the new JSX transform

Answer (score 2):

In `metro.config.js`, set `experimentalImportSupport` to `true`:

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: true,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

Comment: This one did the trick for me when working on a new RN TS project. In older versions we only needed to include the babel configuration specs in order to use the new JSX transform