# React Native Error (ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React) when React is installed?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, jsx

**Overview:**

I created a NPM dependency [react-native-ultimate-modal-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ultimate-modal-picker) and it relies on a few other dependencies.

**Expected Behavior:**

- React should be installed because it's installed in the fresh react project.

**Error:**

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React
```

**What I've tried**

- The components in my NPM Package [react-native-ultimate-modal-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ultimate-modal-picker), all of the components have `react` imported. [Link to Code](https://github.com/jefelewis/react-native-ultimate-modal-picker/tree/master/src/components)
- Installed `react` and `react-native` as `peerDependencies` for my NPM Package [react-native-ultimate-modal-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ultimate-modal-picker)

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I don't get it, where is this error actually occurring?  What's the context

Comment: It's occurring in a fresh react project with the NPM library imported. The error comes up when the iOS Simulator starts

Answer (score 0):

Try importing react like `import React from 'react'` and not `import * as React from 'react'` at the beginning of every module.

Comment: I thought this was no longer required?

Comment: @twiz it is no longer required in React 17 if you enable it. In React Native v0.64+ you can enable it by following these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68143152/5058068